# В чём разница библиотек?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В чём разница между библиотеками с# UnityEngine.UI и UnityEngine.UIElements? Я всегда использовал первое в коде, но после того как я обновился мне чаще стало выдавать второй случай.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/itmai/blog/517726/

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, что UnityEngine.UIElements не является заменой UnityEngine.UI.

Документация по UI: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.html
Документация по UIElements:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UIElements.html

Comment: Понял, Спасибо!